# AttributeError at /profile/create 'ProfileCreate' object has no attribute 'errors'

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-errors

I am working on a social media project and getting this error while creating any profile. Please help me through this. Below is code mentioned.

view.py

```
from multiprocessing import context
from pickle import FALSE
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views import View
from .form import CreateUserForm, ProfileForm
from .models import CustomUser, Profile
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login,logout,authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)

def registration(request):    
    userform = CreateUserForm(request.POST)

    if request.method=='POST':
        
        if userform.is_valid():
            userform.save(commit='FALSE')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'An Error Occured!!')

    Users = CustomUser.objects.all()

    context = {'User': Users, 'form': CreateUserForm }

    return render (request,'registration.html',context)
    
def log_in(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request,username=username,password=password) 

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.info(request,'Username or Password is incorrect')
        
    context = {}
    return render(request,'login.html',context) 

@login_required
def log_out(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.info(request, "Logged out successfully!")
    return redirect('index')


@login_required
def home(request):

    return render(request,'home.html')

class ProfileCreate(CreateView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Profile.objects.all()

    fields = [
        'image',
        'first_name',
        'last_name'
    ]

    template_name = 'profile.html'
    
    success_url = "/home"
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        ProfileForm.save(self)
        return super().form_valid(ProfileForm)

class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Profile
    template_name = "profileview.html"
```

models.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from distutils.command.upload import upload
from email.policy import default
from urllib import request
from django.apps import apps
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


# Create your models here.

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, username, date_of_birth, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given username, email, and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        # Lookup the real model class from the global app registry so this
        # manager method can be used in migrations. This is fine because
        # managers are by definition working on the real model.
        GlobalUserModel = apps.get_model(self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.object_name)
        username = GlobalUserModel.normalize_username(username)
        user = self.model(username=username, date_of_birth=date_of_birth, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.password = make_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    # def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
    #     extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
    #     extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
    #     return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(('email address'),unique= 'TRUE')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    objects = UserManager()
    
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images')
    first_name = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

profile.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Create your Profile First</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}

        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
    </form>

    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows Attribute Errors which says ProfileCreate object has no attribute 'errors'.
But I am not able to find where i mentioned errors and how to remove this error.

This is its traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/create

Django Version: 3.1.5
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['accounts',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shree\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\shree\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shree\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shree\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shree\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 172, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shree\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Users\shree\django\new\accounts\views.py", line 81, in form_valid
    ProfileForm.save(self)
  File "C:\Users\shree\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 451, in save
    if self.errors:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /profile/create
Exception Value: 'ProfileCreate' object has no attribute 'errors'
```

Comment: Do you have a form for creating of profile...? if yes please share it for me to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You've to pass your form inside **POST** method like this

```
def registration(request):    
    userform = CreateUserForm()

    if request.method=='POST':
       userform = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
       if userform.is_valid():
          userform.save(commit='FALSE')
       else:
          messages.error(request,'An Error Occured!!')

    Users = CustomUser.objects.all()

    context = {'User': Users, 'form': CreateUserForm }

    return render (request,'registration.html',context)
```

Comment: But I am using class based view. So, guide me accordingly

Comment: Hello @ParvinderMainn check I've edited my answer